# CRM show data using PHP CURL

Tags: php

I want to show my data on my CRM using PHP with curl and also using API.

If there is any other method. You can kindly show it to me

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://b.maxmind.ma/api/leads",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authtoken: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyfdfdiOjE1ODEwODk2MjJ9.Selc36cmT3XyXH6cGdJ3SN-332kx7"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

?>
```

the response show : **error code: 1020**

Comment: first of all , you have to determinate if it is a post or get ? you make a get call with body content which totaly wrong . this is not the solution for your question but , first , resovle this little problem

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: modify your question after resolving

Comment: Its not resolved

Comment: i told you that it will not resolve the problem . so you mention that the request is a GET not POST , is that true ?

Comment: Its GET not POST

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the website you are trying to request is protected by Cloudflare. 
When i try by the postman , this is the header response a get :

[image]

The error code 1020 you got is from cloudflare .

First, you can try using this solution that bypasses the Cloudflare problem

[KyranRana/cloudflare-bypass](https://github.com/KyranRana/cloudflare-bypass)

If not working, in this case, you must contact the site owner to remove the block ([more here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/error-1020-access-denied/107110/7))